# Do they really need to fear the White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Spoilers for S06E10:

> When Benjen Stark leaves Bran by the tree, he says that he cannot pass
>  the Wall and the dead cannot pass.

Since he was created as he is by the same magic that created the Ice King, that means the Wall will stop them.

What am I missing, or will the sheer volume of undead allow then to tear down the Wall and break its spell?

Comment: How would even a vast army of corpses tear down something that massive?

Comment: "...tear down something that massive?" It's basicly a glacier.  If what I've been reading is true, hair spray will do it.  Also freon and cow farts.

Comment: A couple of points to that, 1) you seem to have man-caused global climate change/warmng  confused with depletion of ozone in the upper atmosphere, so, no, hairspray and freon would have nothing to do with it, and 2) being a cmpletely different world, they don't have hair spray, don't have freon, are not releasing eons of stored CO2 in a compressed timeframe.  What you've been reading seems weak on actual science.

Comment: @Andrew Mattson: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SarcasmBlind?from=Main.DoesNotUnderstandSarcasm

Comment: Oooh, CO2, so what we really have to do, is breath on it. [;)](http://www.thescienceforum.com/general-discussion/46636-there-term-blind-irony-sarcasm-comming-self.html)

Comment: @kl78 - I'm not blind to sarcasm, he just totally whiffed on the basics (as further exemplified by the more recent not so witty comeback), so it falls flat,  It seemed like canned snark that gets broken out whenever possible, regardless of applicability, more than actual sarcasm.

Comment: @AndrewMattson: Blimey, buzzkill much? :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The dead men cannot pass the wall, that is true. Wall was enchanted with ancient magic by its builder to stop the dead men from coming.

But the Wall is not eternal. It can fall. The others will not try to pass through the gates, they will try to bring it down. We know it can be brought down by magical weapons such as [Horn of Joramun](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Joramun) which according to legends has the power to bring down the wall.

According to [GRRM](http://web.archive.org/web/20051103091500/nrctc.edu/fhq/vol1iss3/00103009.htm/):

> “The Others can do things with ice that we can't imagine and make
>   substances of it."

Winter has finally come which means more snow and increase in power of the others.

1. They might make an Icy bridge or stairs over the wall to cross it.
   [image]
2. They might freeze the sea to build an ice road which takes them over the water and lands them on East Watch by The sea.
3. They might build a bridge across the sea all the way down to South.
4. They might bring down the wall using Magic and horn of Joramun.
5. Others have [Ice Spiders](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_spiders) according to the legend. With it being Being a spider, it is safe to assume the beast might be able to climb over the wall with its rider.
6. The wall is not complete. There is a dangerous way to by-pass the wall which has been used by Wildlings to raid and attack the Seven Kingdoms. The region is called [the Gorge](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gorge). It can be used to sneak inside the realm without having to trouble with the wall at all. But only surefoot and strong people can cross it, it's not everyone's cup of tea.
7. Others might try to infiltrate the wall. They have successfully demonstrated that before during the assassination attempt on Jeor Mormont which happened when NW men brought corpses of dead brothers inside Castle Black and at night they rose to kill the Lord Commander. So it appears, others can enter the Wall if a man of the Night's Watch escorts them.

If Wall is not defended by Might of all Men, Others will find a way to by pass it and continue their war against Life.

According to Books however, there is one more point:

> "He's some dead thing. **The monsters cannot pass so long as the Wall
>   stands and the men of the Night's Watch stay true**, that's what Old
>   Nan used to say. He came to meet us at the Wall, but he could not
>   pass. He sent Sam instead, with that wilding girl"

There are two prerequisties for the Wall to deny entry to the others.

1. Wall has to be standing.
2. Men of the Night's Watch have to be true.

As of now, Men of the Night's Watch are not true. They have mutinied twice and killed two of their Lord Commanders. It is very important that Men of NW remain true because if any of them escorts the Others inside, Enchantments won't stop them.

Comment: About truthfulness of NW men: only the first mutiny was against NW and its rules. The second mutiny was because they thought that only lord Snow is wrong and leading NW to completely wrong way. Also, there is an opinion that now NW is more true than before, because all people who want to leave it can leave it, and because of anarchy no one stop and punish him

Comment: @Schullz This is a good point though murdering a lord commander is still betrayal of their allegiance to the LC. It is still insubordination and mutiny even if their motives were good. Jon left but I don't think there is any evidence for any member of NW leaving unscathed. Winterfell is back in Stark hand who will most likely behead deserters like all the Starks before them. Order is being restored.

Comment: yes, information about anarchy in the North after s06e10 is a little bit outdated

Comment: I have trouble taking any of Old Nan's stories as fact, rather than legends.

Comment: @kuhl Legends hold grains of truth in them.

Comment: @Aegon  Why do they even need a bridge or freeze the ocean?  Why cant they take a proverbial move from "pirates of the Caribbean" and simply walk the undead along the ocean floor and walk around the wall?

Comment: "because if any of them escorts the Others inside, Enchantments won't stop them" do you have any evidence for this? I don't get that from Nan's quote, not at all. I read that quote as meaning that the wall also needs to be guarded, it doesn't imply that a member of the NW could help a walker pass the wall. It also doesn't specify what *true* means in this context.

Comment: @terdon You might wanna watch the episode in which NW men bring two wights inside Castle black (Who were pretending to be corpses) and thus the wall's enchantment did not stop them and they rose up to kill LC. Jon saved LC's life and won Longclaw as a reward

Comment: @terdon It is possible for men of NW to try to cut a deal with the Others. The original Night's King (books version) was a Lord commander who rose up as a king and struck a deal with others where he had to make sacrifices to them. Others aren't dumb, they can do politics.

Comment: @Aegon sure they're not dumb. I've always kind of assumed they're more intelligent than humans, anyway. Which episode are your referring to? (and, by the way, if that does show what you describe, that would be a perfect reference to back your claim) Are you sure they weren't actual corpses who woke during the night?

Comment: @terdon It was 8th episode of Season 1, The whole event is transcribed in point seven. They were not corpses, they were abnormal which is why Jeor Mormont commanded to take them to Maester Aemon at Castle Black. Since it's Season 1 thing, I reckoned everyone would be familiar with the event.

Comment: @Aegon OK, I always thought those were simply frozen corpses that rose during the night. I've never seen any evidence suggesting they were already wakened corpses and certainly not that they were night walkers.

Comment: @terdon The NW did not know they were wights, they suspected it. Sam and Jon noted that the corpses don't smell and they are not rotting despite being there for a long while. Other men suggest burning them but LC commanded them to take them to Castle Black and let Aemon examine them to find irregularities.

Comment: Hasn't there been references to the White Walkers attacking during a previous Winter? I remember reading something like that in one of the books. It led me to believe that during the winter they had a way to get past the Wall or that whatever power the Wall had, weakened during the Winter.

Comment: @ricardo Wall was constructed after the Others were defeated in Battle of the Dawn. Then they disappeared from the World and now they are back after 8,000 years. Back when they first rose, there was no wall.

Comment: I would take "stay true" to just mean that they are there to man the wall and take that duty seriously (as they are oath-bound to do). IOW, the walkers could probably find a way to get past it if nobody there is diligent enough to notice them doing so and stops them. I don't think it means the magic somehow senses the inherent moral qualities of the defenders.

Comment: @T.E.D., it's interesting to me that you scoff that it could magically sense its defenders moral qualities, when it's well established in books and show that the wall *is* magic, and that its magic is what has let it stand (in spite of seasonal changes etc) for millennia on end.  There is at least one known case where that magic directly interacts with a man of the Watch and only works because of his oath having been given to the Watch (Sam, the secret gate).  Why is it so far fetched that Nans words might have been more literal?

Comment: "The *might* use some icey newly undead being to melt the wall"

Answer (score 30):

**The mark on Bran's hand.**

[image: Mark on Bran's hand]

In s06e05, we saw the Night King touch Bran's hand which allowed him to pass through the barrier protecting the tree where Bran was hiding.

The legend says that Bran the Builder built the Wall and to amass such a huge amount of magic he must have had help from the Children of the Forest. The children must have used the same magic to protect the cave too.

By that logic, if Bran crosses the Wall then the White Walkers can too.

**EDIT:**
 Some of you mentioned that the Night King used the mark only to find the location of Bran. Here is the conversation that followed between Bran and the Three-Eyed Raven after the Night King touched Bran's hand in S06E05:

> Bran: The Night King, he saw me.
>   Three-Eyed Raven: He touched you. He knows you are here. He'll come for you.
>   Bran: But he can't get in.
>   Three-Eyed Raven: He can now. His mark is on you.

As Forward Ed mentioned in the comments, after touching Bran a part of the Night King was now inside the cave which allowed him to breach the barrier.

Since it was not mentioned in the show whether the mark was removed or not, we can assume it is still there.

Comment: +1, Excellent point. I had completely forgotten about that. It would be pretty disappointing though if that happens.

Comment: Just discussed this with a mate. He appears to be of the idea that Night's King only used Bran to find the cave, he broke the protective charms with his own power.

Comment: @Aegon The night king knows what Bran is capable of. He is a threat and I doubt he would let him go that easily.

Comment: I'm missing something here, because I can't make heads or tails of this answer. What does touching the hand have to do with the wall? Barrier? What barrier? Touching Bran allowed the Night King to find them. Are you saying it did something else also?

Comment: @DCShannon Children of Forrest used magic to keep Night King from cave. Bran lets Night King touch him. Night King now has an in. It is basically vampire logic.

Comment: Did they actually say anything in the show about some kind of ward keeping him out? I was under the impression that they were simply in a secret location. Even if that's the case, how does the last sentence make sense? "By that logic"... what logic?

Comment: I don't think that was addressed specifically.  They were able to locate them once the touch happened, but whether or not they could have breached the spells is open to speculation.

I'd say they were always able to breach the spell, even before the touch, otherwise, why would hiding also be necessary?

Comment: Yup that's what one of my friends seem to believe. He says NK used his touch to find Bran and cave. Then he used his own power to break enchantments on the cave. While he needed to find the cave, he does not need to find the wall. He already knows where it is.

Comment: When Bran first arrived at the cave, there were undead laying beneath the snow that attacked them.  The undead could not enter the cave at that time and were destroyed when they tried to enter.  Going with the assumption that the NK knows what his creation are doing, I think its fair to say that the NK always knew about the cave but was unable to until he had touched Bran.  After touching Bran a part of him was now within the cave and I believe that this is what allows the NK to breach the barrier guarding the cave.

Comment: That assumes that the NK somehow "wargs" them and can see through their eyes, as opposed to commanding/directing them.  Given the mindless nature of their actions, I'm not sure that's a safe assumption.  We need to send a reporter north of the Wall to interview the Night King and find out.

Answer (score 1):

The wall has magic preventing the Others and the wights from tunneling under the ice or from using any of the openings, but I think it does not prevent them from climbing the wall. For example, in A Dance With Dragons, Jon Snow has a dream where he fights wights that climb the wall to attack him at the top. Here is the relevant section (emphasis mine):

> That night he dreamt of wildlings howling from the woods, advancing to the moan of warhorns and the roll of drums. Boom DOOM boom DOOM boom DOOM came the sound, a thousand hearts with a single beat. Some had spears and some had bows and some had axes. Others rode on chariots made of bones, drawn by teams of dogs as big as ponies. Giants lumbered amongst them, forty feet tall, with mauls the size of oak trees.
>
> “Stand fast,” Jon Snow called. “Throw them back.” He stood atop the Wall, alone. “Flame,” he cried, “feed them flame,” but there was no one to pay heed.
>
> They are all gone. They have abandoned me.
>
> Burning shafts hissed upward, trailing tongues of fire. Scarecrow brothers tumbled down, black cloaks ablaze. “Snow,” an eagle cried, as **foemen scuttled up the ice like spiders**. Jon was armored in black ice, but his blade burned red in his fist. As the dead men reached the top of the Wall he sent them down to die again. He slew a greybeard and a beardless boy, a giant, a gaunt man with filed teeth, a girl with thick red hair. Too late he recognized Ygritte. She was gone as quick as she’d appeared.

Considering this, I think the condition that the Men of the Night's Watch need to remain true for the Wall to repel the Others simply means that they need to man the wall in order to prevent the enemy from climbing over it. "A wall is only as good as the men defending it."